# How do I unlock my device after locking it with Device Manager?

Tags: locked-out, android-device-manager

I locked my phone using Device Manager because I lost it. It was returned to me, so now how do I unlock it?

Answer (score 3):

Android Device Manager asked you to set a new password when you locked it.  Use that password.

[image: screenshot]